# Java PreparedStatement RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS not working

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, insert, prepared-statement

I am trying to get the identity column returned to my java program when doing a SQL insert. I am getting the following error when running the code

```
    Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the 
servlet: Cocoon. Exception thrown : java.lang.AbstractMethodError: java/sql
/Connection.prepareStatement(Ljava/lang/String;I)Ljava/sql/PreparedStatement;
```

Here is the code I am running.

```
private void insertUserInputParameters(ReportData rptData){

     UserInputParameters userParams = rptData.getUserInputData();
     StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
     PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;
     int userDataId = -1;

    //Get a database connection.
    sl = ServiceLocator.getInstance();
    ds = sl.getDataSource("jdbc/collegeguide");
    con = ds.getConnection();
    con.setReadOnly(false);

    sql.append("insert into cpgusrdtaf (statecd, addr1, addr2, city, state, ");
    sql.append("zipcode, dependent, shdindic, marstatus, residency, prntatge, ");
    sql.append("fincome, mincome, pincome, taxspaid, taxreturn, elig1040, ");
    sql.append("gincome, pcash, inetwrth, bnetwrth, pbenefit, paddlinf, ");
    sql.append("puntax, pdslcwrk, smstatus, sresidncy, studtr, stud1040, ");
    sql.append("sadjinc, sincome, spincome, sdslcwrk, studtax, scash, ");
    sql.append("sinvest, snetwrth, saddlinf, suntax, househld, nmbrsch, ");
    sql.append("studact, studsat, schools, housing) ");
    sql.append("values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?, ");
    sql.append("?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    //This line of code is where I get the error**
    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString(), Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

    //If I remove the 'Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS' I do not get the error.**
    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

    setStatementValues(pstmt, userParams);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();

    rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
    if(rs.next()){
       userDataId = rs.getInt(1);
    }
```

I am not allowed to use stored procedures, so I cannot go that route. Any help would be greatly appreciated

I am using java 1.5

Thanks in advance
Doug

Comment: Could you post the rest of the relevant code ? Please also include the database used.

Comment: I added more of my code for you. I am inside websphere and connecting to an IBM DB2 database on the iseries.

Comment: What driver? I haven't used DB2 in aeons ...

Comment: The driver we are using is DB2 UDB for iSeries (Toolbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My JT400.jar file was an older version. I downloaded the latest jar file from sourceforge and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the arguments/parameters are balanced

(please confirm the query executes natively, and that the driver supports the RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS),

Can you try to use RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS as part of the argument to an executeUpdate call?

```
pstmt = con.createStatement();
pstmt.executeUpdate(sql.toString(), Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

EDIT:
Just read your note about using DB2. According to http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fimjcc_t0057053.html

_Restriction: For IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ version 3.57 or later, the following form is not valid for inserting rows into a view on a DB2® for z/OS® data server.

Connection.prepareStatement(sql-statement, 
  Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);_

Comment: I have tested using your example and I get the same Error.

Comment: I am not inserting into a view. It is a physical file.

Comment: If the driver supports RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS (which it appears to do from your mention of alternate execution path) then to debug step-by-step appears to be the only viable option

Answer (score 2):

this way it works for me:

```
prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql, new String[]{"NameOfIDField"});
```

I once had a problem with an oracle db where this was not working if the table has many fields.
But the above is working for me even with 60 fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Statement

```
Statement st    = null;
ResultSet rs    = null;
st = con.createStatement();

String query = " INSERT INTO refac_folios
([usuario], [estatus]) VALUES ('" + usuario + "'," + Vista_FoliosRefacciones.ESTATUS_CREADO )" ;

Integer afectadas = st .executeUpdate( query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS );

if (afectadas > 0){

     rs = st.getGeneratedKeys();

     if (rs .next()) {
          folio = rs.getInt(1);
     }
  rs.close();
}
st.close();
```