# Insert data into multiple tables in single transaction in jdbc

Tags: sql, servlets, jdbc

I have a table **Order** which has fields
**Orderid|status|cid|**

and another table
**Order_Details**

**Oder_details_id|Order_id|Item id**

I want to insert values in both the table in single transaction like if a customer place an order so the an order id should be generated and that order_id should be inserted into Order and Order_Details table.
But how do i do in JDBC??

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post some code and show what is not working as expected?

Comment: i've gone through some code which says to either use transaction or stored procedure. Like first (inert order id into order table) then(select orderi_d from order table where date="" and itemid="" ) and insert order_id into order_details tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it setting autocommit to `false`:

```
dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false); // to start a transaction block.

// do your two inserts here

dbConnection.commit(); // to end a transaction block.
```

Take a look here for full example: [JDBC Transaction example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-transaction-example/)

Comment: Will it able to select the Order_Id which is a primary key & Auto Increment in a Order_Table AND insert this Order_Id into Orderdetails Table. In OrderDetails table it is Forign key @Ashot Karakhanyan

Comment: @user2210442, You can at first insert `Order` then `OrderDetails`. When you inserting the `Order` you can retrieve generated `id` (PK) as follow: `PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`. And get it after insert as following: 
`int generatedId;
 try (ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys()) {
     if (rs.next()) {
         generatedId = rs.getInt(1);
     } 
}`
Then you can use that id as a FK when inserting `OrderDatails`.

Comment: Karakhanayan Thanks Sir but one thing more So will it return the just last generated **Order_Id(primary key)** or will it return the all the  previous **Order_Id(primary key)**

Comment: The first case, just generated PK-s.

Comment: can you explain please ..which first case

Comment: Maybe PK-s are more than one, so in general all PK columns - one after one.

Comment: i need just generated primary key for order how do i know which key is recent

Comment: After update yo get iterator(`rs`) after calling `(ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys()` and in while cycle you retrieve all PK columns.
while(rs.next()) {rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2) (if it is String) etc.}

Also you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105815/java-preparedstatement-return-generated-keys-not-working